# Custom formatting for JSON schemas

Tags: json, jsonschema

I am writing a schema to store online course data and would like to specify that the course length must be entered using the following format:

```
___ weeks
```

Ex: 8 weeks, 10 weeks, 1 weeks...( I know that 1 weeks is an issue, but w/e at this point).

How would I require that the data be entered in this format?

In the same vein, if I wanted to specify that the start date had to be entered as, for ex, July 1, 2013, how would I do that?

Also, I'm aware that there's a format for dates in JSON schema. [1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-zyp-json-schema-03#section-3) The problem is that this format doesn't match the one specified above.

Comment: "I'm aware that JSON has a date format."  That must be a surprise to JSON.

Comment: Any relevant comments + answers?

Comment: There are several different date formats described in the JSON schema document.  JSON itself does not "have" a (preferred) date format.  A date is just data.

Comment: But isn't the purpose of the date format in the schema to only allow data to be entered according to a strict structure?

Comment: The purpose of any data schema is to describe the data.  Any enforcement is purely optional.  And JSON exists separately from the JSON schema doc -- only a vanishingly small fraction of JSON data structures are described with schema.

Answer (score 1):

The problem of format is that, according to the [Json Schema Draft 4](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html), validators may support the format or not. Another important think to note is that "The "format" keyword is defined to allow interoperable semantic validation for a fixed subset of values which are accurately described by authoritative resources, be they RFCs or other external specifications."

I think the appropiate Json-Schema property that suits your needs is "pattern". You can use almost any Regular Expression to enforce special format strings.

You can also use custom keys in "format" if you are using an extensible validator. [Javascript tv4](https://github.com/geraintluff/tv4) has added recently support for "format" extensions.